# How to apply Canny edge detector effectively on image using Opencv in Android?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, android

I am making an Android application to detect multiple objects from an image, then process those objects and compare them with reference objects to detect anomalies. I tested different image edge detectors in python and Prewitt operator gave me the best result as shown below https://i.stack.imgur.com/KcZze.png For android, I used Canny edge detector, but the result is not as good as Prewitt as shown below https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZ3DU.png
The purpose of applying Canny edge detector is the detect the largest contour first then extract this contour and detect every object found in this contour (which in my case 3 objects).

Here is the java code I tried

```
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.coffret);

    //compress bitmap
    bmp = getResizedBitmap(bmp, 500);

    Mat rgbMat = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, rgbMat);


    Mat grayMat = new Mat();
    Mat bwMat = new Mat();

    Imgproc.cvtColor(rgbMat, grayMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    Imgproc.equalizeHist(grayMat, grayMat);

    //Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(grayMat, grayMat, 255, Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 40);
    Imgproc.Canny(grayMat, bwMat, 50, 200, 3, false);

    //find largest contour
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Imgproc.findContours(bwMat, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

        double maxArea = -1;
        int maxAreaIdx = -1;
        if (contours.size() > 0) {
            MatOfPoint temp_contour = contours.get(0); //the largest is at the index 0 for starting point
            MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();
            Mat largest_contour = contours.get(0);
            List<MatOfPoint> largest_contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
            for (int idx = 0; idx < contours.size(); idx++) {
                temp_contour = contours.get(idx);
                double contourarea = Imgproc.contourArea(temp_contour);
                //compare this contour to the previous largest contour found
                if (contourarea > maxArea) {
                    //check if this contour is a square
                    MatOfPoint2f new_mat = new MatOfPoint2f( temp_contour.toArray() );
                    int contourSize = (int)temp_contour.total();
                    Imgproc.approxPolyDP(new_mat, approxCurve, contourSize*0.05, true);
                    if (approxCurve.total() == 4) {
                        maxArea = contourarea;
                        maxAreaIdx = idx;
                        largest_contours.add(temp_contour);
                        largest_contour = temp_contour;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (largest_contours.size() >= 1) {
                MatOfPoint temp_largest = largest_contours.get(largest_contours.size()-1);
                largest_contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
                largest_contours.add(temp_largest);
                Imgproc.cvtColor(bwMat, bwMat, Imgproc.COLOR_BayerBG2RGB);
                Imgproc.drawContours(bwMat, largest_contours, -1, new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
            }
        }


    Utils.matToBitmap(bwMat, bmp);

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(180);

    bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), matrix, true);

    imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

As you can notice, using the Prewitt operator the text is clear and contours are more defined. 
I think I am not applying Canny correctly that's why the largest contour is not detected. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: 
Here is the original image
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uG57P.jpg

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are applying Canny edge detector correct. However, sometimes, it could be trick to define proper minimum and maximum values to threshold the edges.

Maybe the interval you are using (i.e., 50 to 200) is large for your purpose. You could try higher minimum and maximum values with tight intervals, for instance, 175 to 200.

As the image gets complex you need to take special care of these parameters. Sometimes, different sections of your image will require different minimum and maximum thresholds. Take a look at this reference, it contains a decent explanation about [Improvement on Canny edge detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector). At the end of this page, there is a explanation of how to *determine the dual-threshold value*.

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer, but I've tried to change several times those parameters but in vain. I've also tried to remore image binarization with no luck.

Comment: Can you attach the origin image to your post?